# Deserialize json string to C# anonymous array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
var data1 = new[] { 
              new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2009, Sales = 1212 },
              new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2009, Sales = 522 },
              new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2010, Sales = 1337 },
              new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2011, Sales = 711 },
              new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2012, Sales = 2245 },
              new { Product = "Product 3", Year = 2012, Sales = 1000 }
          };
            string jsondata =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data1);
```

What I wish to do is deserialize jsondata to same object as in data1 (C# array with anonymous type{string Product, int Year, int Sales})

I tried without success..

```
var dataj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsondata);
            var data = dataj.ToArray();
```

How do I know.. Because the following does not work though it works with the original C# array(data1)

```
foreach (var d in data)
            {
                int a = d.Year;
            }
```

Without creating a separate class, can I do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are trick, howto deserialize it without dynamics. It should be a liiiiitle bit faster. This also can be as generic solution

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Deserialize<T>(this string source, T typeHolder)
    {
        var ltype = typeof(List<>);
        var constructed = ltype.MakeGenericType(new[] { typeHolder.GetType() });

        // deserializing
        return (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(source, constructed) as IList).Cast(typeHolder);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Cast<T>(this IEnumerable x, T typeHolder)
    {
        foreach (var item in x)
        {
            yield return (T)item;
        }
    }
}
```

So, usage:

```
void Main()
{
    var data1 = new[] {
                      new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2009, Sales = 1212 },
                      new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2009, Sales = 522 },
                      new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2010, Sales = 1337 },
                      new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2011, Sales = 711 },
                      new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2012, Sales = 2245 },
                      new { Product = "Product 3", Year = 2012, Sales = 1000 }
                  };

    string jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data1);
    var ob = new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2009, Sales = 1212 };
    var deserializedObject = jsondata.Deserialize(ob);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `dynamic` keyword since `Year` isn't really a property of `JToken`. The runtime binder can retrieve the value though from introspecting the `JToken` though.

This is the only line you have to change:

```
dynamic data = dataj.ToArray();
```

In your original code the type is anonymous, but that doesn't mean it can't know what properties it has.